# Vue - access nested childs using ref

Tags: vue.js, nested, vue-component, ref

I have vue component which I use inside himself - data can have array with subelements and I use this array to render them in loop, and next level, next level etc. according to nesting level.

Now I would like to run child method from parent and then - if statements are ok, also call it to child, next level etc.

I use

```
    <mycomponent
            ref="myFirstLevelRefName"
            (...)
    ></mycomponent>
```

and then:

```
this.$refs.myFirstLevelRefName
```

to call first-level childs. But what about about child nodes? I use them in view in that way:

```
    <mycomponent
            v-for="(subElement, index) in getSubelements()"
            ref="???"
            v-bind:data="subElement"
            v-bind:key="index"
    ></mycomponent>
```

I tried sent this.$refs from child level to console, but it's empty.

How should I set ref name in nested elements and then call them from parent?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

While it is technically possible to access `$refs` of nested children...

```js
Vue.component('mycomponent', {
    template: "#mycomponent",
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mounted() {
    console.log(
      'Second level <input>\'s value:',
      this.$refs.myFirstLevelRefName.$refs.mySecondLevelRefName.value
    )
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<template id="mycomponent">
    <div>
        <input ref="mySecondLevelRefName" value="Hello">
    </div>
</template>

<div id="app">
  <mycomponent ref="myFirstLevelRefName"></mycomponent>
</div>
```

A way of performing parent/deep child, or deep ancestor/sibling communication, for simple scenarios, is using an **event hub**. (For complex scenarios, see [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org).)

You would create a global variable:

```
var eventHub = new Vue(); // use a Vue instance as event hub
```

To emit events you would use in any component:

```
eventHub.$emit('myevent', 'some value');
```

You would, then, in any other component, to listen to that event. The action of that event could be anything, including a **method call** (which is what you want):

```
eventHub.$on('myevent', (e) => {
    console.log('myevent received', e)
    // this.callSomeMethod();
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var eventHub = new Vue(); // use a Vue instance as event hub

Vue.component('component-first', {
    template: "#component-1st",
    methods: {
      myMethod() {
        eventHub.$emit('myevent', 'some value');
      }
    }
});
Vue.component('component-second', {template: "#component-2nd"});
Vue.component('component-third', {
  template: "#component-3rd",
  created() {
    eventHub.$on('myevent', (e) => {
      this.check();
    });
  },
  methods: {
    check() {
      console.log('check method called at 3rd level child');
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<template id="component-1st">
    <div>
        1st level component
        <button @click="myMethod">Trigger event at 1st level component that will call 3rd level child's method</button>
        <hr>
        <component-second></component-second>
    </div>
</template>
<template id="component-2nd">
    <div>
        <component-third></component-third>
    </div>
</template>
<template id="component-3rd">
    <div><h1>3rd level child</h1></div>
</template>

<div id="app">
  <component-first></component-first>
</div>
```

**Note:** If creating a dedicated instance as event hub is something complicated in your environment, you can replace `eventHub` with `this.$root` (inside your components) and use your own Vue instance as hub.

Comment: I know this is a relatively old post but just came across an issue with the event being created several times on component re-renders. Just need to add `eventHub.$off('myevent')` or `this.$root.$off('myevent')` in the beforeDestroy hook for the component

Comment: @HamendraSunthwal could you post a new question and specify your problem better?